# Question regarding Ito representation theorem

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, chaos

Let $H$ be a Gaussian Hilbert space and $H^{:n:}$ be the homogeneous chaos of order $n$.
and let $D_n:=\{(t_1,\cdots,t_n):t_1<t_2<\cdots <t_n\}$.

For each $n\geq 0$ there exists an isometry
\begin{align}
I_n:L^2(D_n)\to H^{:n:}
\end{align}

such that

\begin{align}
I_n(f_1\odot\cdots\odot f_n)=:I(f_1)\cdots I(f_n):.
\end{align}
This isometry is a multiple stochastic integral.

This multiple integral equals the iterated integral.

Let $n\geq 1$. If $F\in L^2(D_n)$ then

\begin{align}
I_n(F)=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{t_n}\cdots\int_0^{t_2}F(t_1,\cdots,t_n)dB_{t_1}\cdots dB_{t_n}
\end{align}

---

The Itô representation theorem states that that any random variable $X$ in
$L^2(\Omega,\mathcal F(H),\mathbb P)$ can be written as a stochastic integral of some square integrable predictable process $Y$.

Consider a random variable $X\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal F(H),\mathbb P)$ and it's orthogonal projection on $H^{:n:}$.
Hence we have

\begin{align}
\pi_n(X)=I_n(F)\\
\pi_n(X)=I(I_{n-1}(F))
\end{align}
for some $F\in L^2(D_n)$.

(Where $I_{n-1}(F)$ is a square integrable predictable random variable.)

Hence by writting down the chaos decomposition of $X$ and by linearity of the stochastic integral we have that $X$ can be written as a stochastic integral of some square integrable predictable process.

\begin{align}
X&=E(X)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\pi_n(X)\\
&=E(X)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}I(I_{n-1}(F_{n}))\\
&\color{red}{=}E(X)+I\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n-1}(F_{n})\right)
\end{align}

---

1. How do we justify changing the order of summation/integration in the last step?
2. Does the fact that each element in the series on the last expression is square integrable imply that the series itself will be square integrable? Don't we need to require some further condition?

I may have done some mistake or took the wrong path, so any advice is welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your title, do you mean 'question' rather than 'doubt'?

Comment: Changed, thanks!

Comment: You may want to search for “Clark-Ocone formula”...

Comment: Don't forget the condition in the Itô representation theorem that $X$ must have mean zero.  And I don't understand your two equations with $\pi_n$; it seems as though $F$ is standing for two different things.

Comment: But as for the computation at the end, since $I$ is an isometry of Hilbert spaces, it is linear and continuous, and so it will commute with infinite sums that converge with respect to the appropriate Hilbert norm.